# facebook exchange as a website owner/ad-publisher

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads

My boss discovered an article about doubleclick(google) joining facebook exchange and the Real-Time-Bidding System they have. And obviously he is eager to implement this in spots where we have ad-space to give away (not doubleclick, facebook exchange!).

I've tried to dig into facebook exchange and how to implement it and have found out that a user has to give our site permissions (ad) so that facebook gives us ads optimized for this user. This isn't a problem as we ask for basic-information already.

The part that I dont understand is how we'd display ads in a classic 3rd-party-javascript ad code. I've seen methods for performing bids on interests (on the backend though) but that would meen we'd need to create a system where we collect all our user interests, sort them and then bid for the most common interests and then serve these ads somehow magically to the user that actually has that interest. Seems like a huge pain for devs, which facebook couldn't afford. Or can they?

I've found [Dynamic Ad Creative](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/rtb/#dynamicadcreative) that seems to be what I am searching for but when I look at the expample its not. I am aware that FB Exchange shouldn't be some ad-network àla adsense but it still seems awkward that there isn't a simple documentation for ad-publishers. Even if it says "this is not the droid you are looking for".

I'd be thankful for any help/tips/explanations of what facebook exchange actually is and how a website owner could profit/show targeted ads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook Exchange is a way for ad buyers to purchase advertising inventory on Facebook via real-time bidding. You cannot publish Facebook Exchange ads on your site.

In other words, it's yet another way to buy ads on Facebook. Nothing more. The Google/Facebook announcement means that you can now buy ads on Facebook through DoubleClick, including retargeting ads. It doesn't mean you can sell ad space on your site through Facebook.